# How to keep same baseline skip in two vertically aligned minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I have two minipages (actually one of them is varwidth) standing one above the other. How can I keep same baseline skip in them?

I have somewhat strange layout, so I can't set `[t]` option for lower minipage/varwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent LOREM IPSUM

\vfill

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\raggedleft

LOREM IPSUM

LOREM IPSUM
\end{minipage}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
LOREM IPSUM
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\hfill\begin{varwidth}[b]{.5\textwidth}
LOREM IPSUM

LOREM IPSUM

\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two minipages set one above other]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

TeX automatically does the right thing if the baseline of the top box is on its bottom baseline and that of the bottom box is on its top baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
LOREM IPSUM

LOREM IPSUM
\end{minipage}

\noindent
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth}
LOREM IPSUM

LOREM IPSUM
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indicate it, but lower varwidth is [b]. I would modificate MWE now.

Comment: @web-stranger why not make it t:-)

Comment: you're right. Seems it's a subject for another question :).

Comment: I edited question so you could see now why i can't put [b] in the varwidth. Maybe there is another way to keep baseline or to make such layout?