# longtable spacing problems with minipages inside cells

Tags: longtable, minipage

I'm new in [tex.se] and I want to ask you how do I correct the problem I have with this snippet:

```
\section{Latex meltdown my brain!!!}

This longtable table shows a weird behaviour. If I don't use a minipage, the result doesn't show as I want

I show you various problems I've encountered mixing the 3 variants: equal size, one more than another, and viceversa.

\begin{longtable}{@{} p{0.48\textwidth} p{0.48\textwidth} @{}}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
Column fine & Column with problems \\
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                             & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. \\ Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue \end{minipage}\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                                       & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Integer condimentum elit a finibus. \\ Praesent sed vestibulum sapien. \\ Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut. \\ Morbi at malesuada erat. \end{minipage}\\
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus: \\ Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor \end{minipage}\\
\end{longtable}

\clearpage
```

This code, when I use XeTeX and nice fonts, output this:

[image: The problem shows here!]

The packages I used for minimal compiling this snippet are the follows (it could be compiled without most of them, I don't tested with less packages):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

The document type is a:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
```

I've tried to change `\par` with `\noindent` prior to `\begin{minipage}`, with no noticeable changes.

I've tried using the solution approach commented here: [Problem with balancing multicols with minipage inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241491/153762) but it doesn't work, too.

The question is: **What I type into the longtable table or in the minipages to look with correct spacing in the upper and lower parts of the cell?**

The minimal compilable document is:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

    \section{Latex meltdown my brain!!!}

    This longtable table shows a weird behaviour. If I don't use a minipage, the result doesn't show as I want

    I show you various problems I've encountered mixing the 3 variants: equal size, one more than another, and viceversa.

    \begin{longtable}{@{} p{0.48\textwidth} p{0.48\textwidth} @{}}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    Column fine & Column with problems \\
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                             & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. \\ Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue \end{minipage}\\
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                                       & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Integer condimentum elit a finibus. \\ Praesent sed vestibulum sapien. \\ Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut. \\ Morbi at malesuada erat. \end{minipage}\\
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA & \par\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus: \\ Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor \end{minipage}\\
    \end{longtable}

    \clearpage

\end{document}
```

I followed the anotations by Andrew Swann, putting `\strut` at the beggining and the end of the cell, and there is no better spacing around them:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{} p{0.48\textwidth} p{0.48\textwidth} @{}}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
Column fine & Column with problems \\
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                             & \strut\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. \\ Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue \end{minipage}\strut\\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA                                       & \strut\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Integer condimentum elit a finibus. \\ Praesent sed vestibulum sapien. \\ Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut. \\ Morbi at malesuada erat. \end{minipage}\strut\\
BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA & \strut\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus: \\ Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor \end{minipage}\strut\\
\end{longtable}
```

[image: After strut]

I try to achieve, exactly, a bit more spacing between minipage and the start/end of the cell in the longtable, without adding extra spacing inside each minipage.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please collect these snippets in to a minimal compilable document so that others can try your code.  Does it help to add `\strut` and the beginning and the end of the text in the cells?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: I edit the snippets into a minimal compilable document, and I will copy the `\strut`parameter you comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the reason to include minipages in a longtable. If I remove them and make the whole table a bit prettier, we get this code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl, array, booktabs}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{@{} m{0.48\textwidth} m{0.48\textwidth} @{}}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    Column fine & Column with problems \\\addlinespace[1ex]
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA &
    In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. \newline Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue \\\addlinespace[1ex]
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA &  Integer condimentum elit a finibus. \newline Praesent sed vestibulum sapien. \newline Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut. \newline Morbi at malesuada erat. \\\addlinespace[1ex]
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA &  Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus: \newline Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor \\
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I switched to pdftex, so if you need xetex or whatever, remove fontenc and uncomment fontspec.

Result:

[image]

### EDIT

I switched the columns to from p to m, which balances their content vertically, as can be observed in the new picture.

Comment: If you quit the minipage, the `column fine` doesn't show centered vertically, that's why I used minipages to dirty-achieve this.

The pdftex is not a problem, the fonts I used are linked locally and are not relevant into the minimal compilation unit.

Comment: for columns specifiers instead of `p{...}` try to use `m{...}`.

Comment: @Zarko That's why I loaded array for, but then forgot. Corrected, thank you.

Comment: Good anotation! I will try to use this!

Comment: I tried to put  \addlinespace[1ex] in every row, but unafortunately there is no extra spacing in coloured rows

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos Then remove the `\addlinespace` commands and add before `\begin{longtable}` the command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50355/153762: `\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}` and  `\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}`

at the end of the row you want to expand and it works!

The main reason I prefer minipages instead of new lines is I will put there a complete page, involving graphics and text. It gives me more precision than using only tables with their content, just like handcrafting a HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

a (small) variation of [Keks Dose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464299/longtable-spacing-problems-with-minipages-inside-cells/464312#464312) answer:

- different definition of columns width (now the table width is equal to `\textwidth`)
- used the `xcolor` package which is already loaded by the `tikz` package (it is not clear why you declare `svgnames` options for `xcolor` but than not used it)
- for coloring of table's roes are used `rowcolors` from `xtable`
- vertical space around cells is added partly in column definition (for bottom distance) and partly with `\extrarowheight` (for upper distance)
- used the `raggede2e` package for "smart" hyphenation of the cells' contents

  ```
  \documentclass[table, svgnames]{book}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{kpfonts}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \usepackage{tikz}               % it load `"xcolor" with options given in "book" options
                                  % which with option "table" replace "color" and "colortbl"
  \definecolor{MyDarkGray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}  % new
  \definecolor{MyLightGray}{HTML}{EFEFEF} % new
  \usepackage{ragged2e}           % new
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{booktabs,
              longtable}
  \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}<{\smallskip}}  % new

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begingroup
      \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}     % new
      \rowcolors{3}{MyLightGray}{white}  % new
  \begin{longtable}{ *{2}{M{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}} }
      \rowcolor{MyDarkGray}
  Column fine &   Column with problems                    \\
  BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA
      &   In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. % \newline
          Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue          \\
  BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA
      &  Integer condimentum elit a finibus.              \newline
      Praesent sed vestibulum sapien.                     \newline
      Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut.      \newline
      Morbi at malesuada erat.                            \\
  BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA
      &  Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus:            \newline
      Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor
  \end{longtable}
      \endgroup
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose some improvements to add spme vertical padding to the rows, playing with the booktabs parameters. I also suggest to us the `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of v`longtable`   to `tabularx`. Last, I took the opportunity to simplify your preamble, as soma packages are already loaded  by others (e.g. `xltabular` loads `tabularx`, which loads `array`, or the `table` option for `xcolor`, lready loaded by `tikz`, loads  `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass[svgnames, table]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

{%
\defaultaddspace=1ex
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulewidth=1ex
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}XX @{}}
\cmidrule[1ex](lr){1-2}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
    Column fine & Column with problems \\[1ex]
 \addlinespace
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA &
    In eget tortor libero. Duis vulputate scelerisque. \newline Etiam nec ornare nisi, eu semper augue \\
    \addlinespace
    \arrayrulecolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA & Integer condimentum elit a finibus. \newline Praesent sed vestibulum sapien. \newline Donec molestie eros nulla, et finibus urna ut. \newline Morbi at malesuada erat. \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    \addlinespace
    BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA BLABLA BLABLABLA BLABLA BLA & Praesent sit amet condimentum lectus: \newline Butvitae dignissim sem tortor ut dolor \\
    \end{xltabular}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]